# Append binary values column wise in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, character-encoding

I want the binary value of string to get stored in array column wise.

```
st = "hello world"
st = st.encode('utf-8')
# binary value for letter 'h'
bin(st[0]) -> '0b1101000'
# binary value for letter 'e'
bin(st[1]) -> '0b1100101'
```

and so on...

I want to store these binary strings in array as below:

```
0  1  
0  0
0  1
1  0
0  0
1  1
1  1
b  b
0  0
```

Thanks,
Neeraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.fromstring` and `np.unpackbits`:

```
>>> a = np.unpackbits(np.fromstring(st, np.uint8)).reshape((8, -1), order='F')[::-1]
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

This does not contain the `b` character. If you must have that:

```
>>> np.r_['0,2,1', a.astype('U1')[:7], np.full(a.shape[1], 'b'), np.full(a.shape[1], '0')]
array([['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
       ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
       ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
       ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
       ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']],
      dtype='<U1')
```